# In CSS, how to make the window non-scrollable when an element overflows?

Tags: html, css, animation, overflow

Below are the codes:

```css
div.circle {
 height: 134px;
 width: 134px;
 background-color: #000;
 margin: 50vh auto 0;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation-name: expand;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
 animation-direction: alternate;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}


@keyframes expand {
 from {height:134px; width: 134px;}
 to {height:2000px; width:2000px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

When the circle becomes larger than the window, the window becomes scrollable and a scrollbar will appear when I scroll the mouse. Using `overflow:hidden` cannot prevent this..

Does anyone have ideas about how to hide the scrollbar and lock the window when an element becomes larger than the window?

Comment: Add this css: `body{overflow: hidden;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` would work if you apply it to the `body` not your circle

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.circle {
 height: 134px;
 width: 134px;
 background-color: #000;
 margin: 50vh auto 0;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation-name: expand;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
 animation-direction: alternate;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}


@keyframes expand {
 from {height:134px; width: 134px;}
 to {height:2000px; width:2000px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```